# iOS StackExchange app doesn't handle non-ASCII correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, ios-app, unicode

The iOS StackExchange app doesn't handle non-ASCII characters correctly, see city name in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: It's probably sending data as if it will be parsed as HTML.

Comment: There should be no reason for using HTML entities in the first place though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way the StackExchange API works, there is indeed some need to decode HTML entities. In this case, the location on a User was not being decoded.

Fixed in version 0.1.26.

Comment: So now user with name like *`Joe <script>alert('hacked');</script>`* will cause alert to show for any user visiting his profile? ;-)